# Existence and uniqueness of solution of a non linear SDE

Tags: stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis, stochastic-differential-equations

I have the following SDE: $dX_t=(\mu+X_t^2) dt+e^t dB_t$. What can I say about existence and uniqueness of solutions?

I would like to verify the usual conditions of sub-linear growth and Lipschitz, but it seems to me that they are not fulfilled. Can you help me?

Thank you very much!! :)